# Android Bitmap Storing in Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, bitmap, rss

I am working on a News Reader app and currently when the device has internet to download articles, it downloads the article title, text, image etc. and stores it all to an sqlite database. This way if the device doesn't have internet or the user saves an article for offline reading, the article content can still be viewed. My app lags when downloading the articles and doesn't show the images in the listview very good. It is very choppy and isn't good. What is the best way to store this data and access it fast and reliably? Also I need a Lazy Loader that does not require a image's url, is there any that can use images stored on the sdcard for example?

My download method consists of starting a background service to download the articles text and image and updating each items row in the sqlite database, all done in the background. I can post code also, if needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For saving images I prefer to save it on SD card directly not into SQLite.

I recommend to use external Library for downloading images and cashing such as [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

But if you still want to save it into SQLite, here you go:

Setting up your Table

```
CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + "("+ 
               KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + 
               KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB);";
```

Insert into database

```
    public void addImage( String name, byte[] image) throws SQLiteException {

        database.beginTransaction();
        try {
            ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_NAME,    name);
            cv.put(KEY_IMAGE,   image);
            database.insert( DB_TABLE, null, cv );
       } finally {
           database.endTransaction();
       }
    }
```

Retrieve

```
byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(1);
```

Comment: You might want to wrap your database operation in a transaction - see [android example updating database using a transaction](http://android.codota.com/scenarios/528e1e21da0ae9404ad3ab53/android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase?tag=bumblebee)

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you store your images in the database. Instead why dont you save your images in a disk cache, and save the key to the image in your db. Try using [DiskLruCache](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache). It's pretty simple. BTW, I don't recommend you save your image in the database for the following reasons:

1. The images are huge, even if you store them like a varchar, the amount of data will slow down your transaction.
2. If you want even more performance, you can implement a two levels cache, the first level with a memory cache and the second one with a disk cache.